# How to read sql server view in python?

Tags: python, azure, jdbc, azure-functions, odbc

I am trying to read some data from a sql view. I am pyodbc driver for that, I found out that pyodbc cannot read views. Is there is a way to read sql view in a python function?

Here is a piece of sample code:

```
import logging
    import json
    import pyodbc
    import azure.functions as func


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:

    server = '***.database.windows.net'
    database = '**'
    username = '**'
    password = '**'
    driver = '{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}'

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';PORT=1433;SERVER='+server +
                      ';PORT=1443;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD=' + password)

if req.method == 'GET':
    result = []
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not terminal_name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            return func.HttpResponse(
                "Invalid input Json response",
                status_code=401
            )
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')
            id = req_body.get('id')

    query = f"""
                Select distinct([product_type]), product_grade from  cns_terminal_cockpit.v_terminal_outage 
                where terminal_id ={id} and lower(name) = '{name}' 
                and product_grade <> ''
            """

    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute(query)
    except TypeError:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            'Failed. The issue is with the query',
            status_code=402
        )

    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        result.append(
            dict(zip([column[0] for column in cursor.description], row))
        )
    del cnxn

    return func.HttpResponse(
        json.dumps(result, default=str),
        mimetype="application/json",
        status_code=200
    )
else:
    return func.HttpResponse(
        'Wrong request method was posted, please use GET method',
        status_code=403
    )
```

I output json I get is [] and status_code = 200. But in the backend, I have some data in the view. When I query a normal db tables, the same code work's like a charm.

I have looked into other libraries like pymysql, jdbc. But none seems to be working as expected.

Comment: Can you show us the relevant parts of your code? What happens when you run it? Do you get an error? If so, what error?

Comment: Agree, please post code and error, along with link to where you found this out.  Otherwise someone else will come and see *pyodbc can't select from views*.  Which is very, very likely incorrect.  Now, maybe whatever you are using around this, like an ORM, has some problems.  But's that's not on pyodbc itself.

Comment: It results in a null json response. There is no error as such, it's just that it returns a null Json. I am using Pyodbc connector, I get no errors,

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what you get when you `print(query)`

Comment: Is `distinct([product_type])`, with only one of the selected columns in parentheses `(` and `)` valid SQL syntax (for MSSQL)? Are you throwing away an error (if it's not valid) by using `except TypeError:` (too specific), instead of just `except:`?

Comment: It worked, the issue was my driver was outdated. I updated my SQL driver to 17. Then I was able to connect with my sql view

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure where you read that, but it should be straight forward to read data from a view:

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect ('CONNECTION_STRING')

cursor=conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM VIEW')

for row in cursor:
    print(row)
```

Comment: It results in a null json response. There is no error as such, it's just that it returns a null Json.

Answer (score 2):

It worked, the issue was my driver was outdated. I updated my SQL driver to 17. Then I was able to connect with my sql view